# How to Hide STL Functor Structs in C++ Without Granting Private Member Access

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a class, which stores items in an std::unordered_map.  The key for the map is a custom type, so I have a helper struct defined as follows:

```
struct hash_equ {
    // Hasher
    size_t operator()(myType const &val) const;

    // Equality comparer
    bool operator()(myType const &a, myType const &b) const;
};
```

Then, within the class declaration, I have the following:

```
class Foo {
private:
    typedef std::unordered_map<myType const &, int, hash_equ, hash_equ> map_type;

    map_type _myMap;

    ...
};
```

The problem is that I want to hide the existence of `hash_equ` from code outside *Foo.cpp*, but `hash_equ` must be defined in *Foo.h* in order to declare the member `Foo::_myMap`.  The only idea I could come up with is to declare `hash_equ` as a private, inner class of `Foo`.  However, in C++11, doing so would grant access to `Foo` private members to `hash_equ`.  Is there some way to hide `hash_equ` from the client while also preventing access to `Foo`'s private members?

Comment: You could hide it in a details namespace.  SOP is not to access anything in a details namespace if you are not the implementer.

Comment: Isn't that what the [PIMPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) is good for.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [private, implementation, namespace](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/3cryhl/correct_way_to_use_namespace_detail/)?

```
// This can be in either Foo.h or in a file included by it 
namespace detail
{

    struct hash_equ 
    ...

}
```

and then use it like this:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<
    myType const &, 
    int, 
    detail::hash_equ, 
    detail::hash_equ>
```